# Allocators: "No members available". How can I fix that?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, allocation

So, on the lower line of presented code I have IntelliSense warning: "No members available". What's wrong? In normal case there appear to be options, like "allocate", "deallocate", etc.

```
namespace MyLib
{
    template <typename T,
        template <typename Y> class Allocator = std::allocator>
    class Vector
    {
    private:
        std::size_t capacityV;
        std::size_t sizeV;
        T* arr;
    public:
        typedef Allocator<T> AllocatorType;
        typedef Vector<T, Allocator> VectorType;
        template<typename T>
        using AllocTraits = std::allocator_traits<Allocator<T>>;

        std::allocator_traits<Allocator<T>>::    //HERE!
```

Actually, `std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<T>>::` doesn't work too. But works in these case (just as `std::allocator_traits<Allocator<T>>::`):

```
template <
    typename T,
    template <typename Y> class Allocator = std::allocator> // use std::allocator as default allocator
std::unique_ptr<T, std::function<void(T*)>> move_with_allocator(
    T&& stack_object, Allocator<T> allocator = Allocator<T>())
{
    using AllocTraits = std::allocator_traits<Allocator<T>>;
    std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<T>>::allocate(allocator, 1);    //WORKING FINE HERE
```

Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want [Template Intellisense](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/template-intellisense/). Intellisense can give better hints if it has an idea about possible template parameters.